# Scrapy- exceptions.ImportError: No module named middlewares

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Please someone help me out where i'm missing to find the solution for the    **exceptions.ImportError: No module named middlewares** thrown by my code.

My folder structure is:

[image]

Here is my **DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES** in settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'IpRotation.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
    'IpRotation.ProxyMiddleware.ProxyMiddleware': 800,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : None,
    'IpRotation.RotateUserAgentMiddleware.RotateUserAgentMiddleware':350
}
```

My Spider program:

```
import scrapy    
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "dmoz"
        allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
        start_urls = [
            "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
            "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
        ]

        def parse(self, response):
            filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
```

My Custom UserAgentMiddleware.py :

```
import logging
import random
import scrapy
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent import UserAgentMiddleware

class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(UserAgentMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, user_agent=''):
        self.user_agent = user_agent

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        user_agent_list = [....]
        ua = random.choice(user_agent_list)
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)   
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request)
```

My Custom IPRotationMiddleWare.py :

```
import random
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy import HttpProxyMiddleware

class ProxyMiddleware(HttpProxyMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, proxy_ip=''):
        self.proxy_ip = proxy_ip

    def process_request(self,request,spider):
        ip = random.choice(self.proxy_list)
        if ip:
            request.meta['proxy']= ip


    proxy_list = [.......]
```

I am unable to find the issue with the middlewares named exception.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes with your `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` where you have in first place:

```
'IpRotation.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
```

This looks for the `MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware` in the `middlewares` module. And if this file does not exist (`middlewares.py`) then you get the error.

Make sure your settings are correct for the other middlewares too.

Comment: Keeping things simple, What I need to with scrapy is to send proxy requests. So I overriden the UserAgentMiddleware class and HttpProxyMiddleware class and everything is similar. Now my question is, What I need to implement in middleware.py module. I am absolutely clue less with middleware.py implementation in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is a simple one..

change

```
'IpRotation.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
```

to

```
'IpRotation.middleware.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
```

your file is middleware.py. Notice its not middleware**s**.py